# get instance from model to save to foreignkey field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

i don't really understand what this instance was implying

"Cannot assign "15": "Cart.Product_ID" must be a "Product" instance."

"15" is the primary key of Model.Product and i want to insert it into Model.Cart

views.py

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = TempCart(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            VarProductId = Product.objecrs.get(PId="Product_ID")
            VarHowMany = request.POST.get('HowMany')
            VarDateSubmit = request.POST.get('DateSubmit')
            Cart_obj = Cart(Product_ID = VarProductId, HowMany = VarHowMany, DateSubmit = VarDateSubmit)
            Cart_obj.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/Catalogue')
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    PId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    # and other fields

class Cart(models.Model):
    Product_ID = models.ForeignKey(Product,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    HowMany = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    DateSubmit = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

html

```
<form method="post" action="" id="CartInput"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <input name="Product_ID" type="hidden" value="{{ Product.pk }}" >
        <input name="HowMany" type="number" value="1" id="HowMany" >
        {{ CartForm.DateSubmit }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="Cart{{ Product.PId }}" type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
    </div>
</form>
```

am i missing something here?
maybe i have to save the whole queryset for Product_ID(foreignkey)?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Edit:

Don't know if this might help

```
ValueError at /Catalogue/
Cannot assign "'14'": "Cart.Product_ID" must be a "Product" instance.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Catalogue/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Cannot assign "'14'": "Cart.Product_ID" must be a "Product" instance.
Exception Location: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py in __set__, line 211
Python Executable:  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\Wildcard91\\Wildcard91',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg']
Server time:    Tue, 21 Mar 2017 15:36:04 +0700
Traceback Switch back to interactive view


Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Catalogue/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.postgres',
 'Shop.apps.ShopConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Wildcard91\Wildcard91\Shop\views.py" in post
  180.         if form.is_valid():

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  169.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  161.             self.full_clean()

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  372.         self._post_clean()

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg\django\forms\models.py" in _post_clean
  393.             self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg\django\forms\models.py" in construct_instance
  65.             f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in save_form_data
  833.         setattr(instance, self.name, data)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __set__
  211.                     self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,

Exception Type: ValueError at /Catalogue/
Exception Value: Cannot assign "'14'": "Cart.Product_ID" must be a "Product" instance.



Share this traceback on a public website
Request information

USER
Wildcard91
GET
No GET data
POST
Variable    Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken 
'o9dVi0XNWtAA5ZV5dsz4pJ8gKRrC3jtjpC8XKVPaqnyCmzi632zmNN8z0jeoYseQ'
Product_ID  
'14'
HowMany 
'1'
DateSubmit  
'2017-03-21 15:36:00.819886'
initial-DateSubmit  
'2017-03-21 15:36:00.819886'
Cart14  
'Add to Cart'
FILES
No FILES data
COOKIES
Variable    Value
sessionid   
'5sctxyy2mfier9zptze2t5te96n4zvod'
csrftoken   
'jP6kYDKo7hGEMxLq5Dyuq5QeNB30SPTEki1mqyCLBbEG378rVdyMO9Qx33QMNYEb'
META
Variable    Value
ALLUSERSPROFILE 
'C:\\ProgramData'
APPDATA 
'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming'
CLASSPATH   
'.;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\QuickTime\\QTSystem\\QTJava.zip'
COMMONPROGRAMFILES  
'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'
COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86) 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'
COMMONPROGRAMW6432  
'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'
COMPUTERNAME    
'USER-PC'
COMSPEC 
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe'
CONTENT_LENGTH  
'766'
CONTENT_TYPE    
'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryuDZj0ni1h91jG0yg'
CSRF_COOKIE 
'jP6kYDKo7hGEMxLq5Dyuq5QeNB30SPTEki1mqyCLBbEG378rVdyMO9Qx33QMNYEb'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  
'Wildcard91.settings'
DNX_HOME    
'%USERPROFILE%\\.dnx'
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK    
'NO'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
'CGI/1.1'
HOMEDRIVE   
'C:'
HOMEPATH    
'\\Users\\User'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip, deflate, br'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'en-US,en;q=0.8'
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  
'max-age=0'
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'keep-alive'
HTTP_COOKIE 
('sessionid=5sctxyy2mfier9zptze2t5te96n4zvod; '
 'csrftoken=jP6kYDKo7hGEMxLq5Dyuq5QeNB30SPTEki1mqyCLBbEG378rVdyMO9Qx33QMNYEb')
HTTP_HOST   
'127.0.0.1:8000'
HTTP_ORIGIN 
'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
HTTP_REFERER    
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/Catalogue/'
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  
'1'
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like '
 'Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36')
LOCALAPPDATA    
'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local'
LOGONSERVER 
'\\\\USER-PC'
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS    
'4'
OS  
'Windows_NT'
PATH    
('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS '
 'Client\\;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program '
 'Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program '
 'Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files '
 '(x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program '
 'Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files '
 '(x86)\\AMD\\ATI.ACE\\Core-Static;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA '
 'Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\Program Files '
 '(x86)\\QuickTime\\QTSystem\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL '
 'Server\\100\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL '
 'Server\\100\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL '
 'Server\\100\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\.dnx\\bin;C:\\Program '
 'Files\\Microsoft DNX\\Dnvm\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL '
 'Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\;C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Scripts\\;C:\\Program '
 'Files\\Git\\cmd\\;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\;C:\\Program '
 'Files\\Git\\bin\\;C:\\Program '
 'Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Users\\User\\.dnx\\bin;C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm')
PATHEXT 
'.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY'
PATH_INFO   
'/Catalogue/'
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE  
'AMD64'
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER    
'Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel'
PROCESSOR_LEVEL 
'6'
PROCESSOR_REVISION  
'3c03'
PROGRAMDATA 
'C:\\ProgramData'
PROGRAMFILES    
'C:\\Program Files'
PROGRAMFILES(X86)   
'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
PROGRAMW6432    
'C:\\Program Files'
PROMPT  
'$P$G'
PSMODULEPATH    
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\'
PUBLIC  
'C:\\Users\\Public'
QTJAVA  
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\QuickTime\\QTSystem\\QTJava.zip'
QUERY_STRING    
''
REMOTE_ADDR 
'127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_HOST 
''
REQUEST_METHOD  
'POST'
RUN_MAIN    
'true'
SCRIPT_NAME 
''
SERVER_NAME 
'User-PC'
SERVER_PORT 
'8000'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'WSGIServer/0.2'
SESSIONNAME 
'Console'
SYSTEMDRIVE 
'C:'
SYSTEMROOT  
'C:\\Windows'
TEMP    
'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
TMP 
'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
USERDOMAIN  
'User-PC'
USERNAME    
'User'
USERPROFILE 
'C:\\Users\\User'
VS100COMNTOOLS  
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\Tools\\'
VS140COMNTOOLS  
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\Tools\\'
WINDIR  
'C:\\Windows'
WINDOWS_TRACING_FLAGS   
'3'
WINDOWS_TRACING_LOGFILE 
'C:\\BVTBin\\Tests\\installpackage\\csilogfile.log'
wsgi.errors 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
wsgi.file_wrapper   
''
wsgi.input  
<_io.BufferedReader name=800>
wsgi.multiprocess   
False
wsgi.multithread    
True
wsgi.run_once   
False
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
wsgi.version    
(1, 0)
Settings
Using settings module Wildcard91.settings
Setting Value
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
ADMINS  
[]
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
[]
APPEND_SLASH    
True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS    
'********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'auth.User'
BASE_DIR    
'C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\Wildcard91\\Wildcard91'
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE 
31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME    
'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS    
[]
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': 'Wildcard91Db',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': 'postgres'}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS   
1000
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y']
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG   
True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
'.'
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/html'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
[]
EMAIL_BACKEND   
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST  
'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
'********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
''
EMAIL_PORT  
25
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  
None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   
'********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
'[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT   
None
EMAIL_USE_SSL   
False
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
False
FILE_CHARSET    
'utf-8'
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   
None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
None
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
FIXTURE_DIRS    
[]
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
[]
INSTALLED_APPS  
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.postgres',
 'Shop.apps.ShopConfig']
INTERNAL_IPS    
[]
LANGUAGES   
[('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('ast', 'Asturian'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('io', 'Ido'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('mr', 'Marathi'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
['he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE 
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
LOCALE_PATHS    
[]
LOGGING 
{}
LOGGING_CONFIG  
'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/accounts/profile/'
LOGIN_URL   
'/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL 
None
MANAGERS    
[]
MEDIA_ROOT  
'C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\Wildcard91\\Wildcard91\\media'
MEDIA_URL   
'/media/'
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE  
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES  
['django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES   
{}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
PASSWORD_HASHERS    
'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
'********************'
PREPEND_WWW 
False
ROOT_URLCONF    
'Wildcard91.urls'
SECRET_KEY  
'********************'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER   
False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF 
False
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  
False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS 
0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  
[]
SECURE_SSL_HOST 
None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT 
False
SERVER_EMAIL    
'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
SESSION_SERIALIZER  
'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'Wildcard91.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND 
'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  
[]
STATICFILES_DIRS    
[]
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT 
None
STATIC_URL  
'/static/'
TEMPLATES   
[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': [],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    
[]
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
','
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE   
'UTC'
USE_ETAGS   
False
USE_I18N    
True
USE_L10N    
True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
USE_TZ  
True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT    
False
WSGI_APPLICATION    
'Wildcard91.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
'SAMEORIGIN'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
'F Y'
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard page generated by the handler for this status code.
```

Comment: You definitely have to read PEP8...

Comment: @AndreyShipilov yikes,  that's a lot of material to cover @.@ hahah

Comment: That's a coding style, you need to use it if you want to have a readable code.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem,  guess it's my fault for not including forms.py in the question

THE WRONG ONE

```
class TempCart(forms.ModelForm):
    Product_ID = forms.CharField(max_length=80, label="Product ID")
    HowMany = forms.IntegerField(label='HowMany')
    DateSubmit = forms.DateTimeInput()
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ["Product_ID","HowMany","DateSubmit",]
```

Problem was with the fields

all it takes to fix the problem is deleting the "Product_ID"

```
fields = ["HowMany","DateSubmit",]
```

Thank you all for helping me

Cheers

***but if it is not too much to ask can anyone explain why this is happening?
why do django decilne the "Product_ID" on the fields?***

Answer (score 0):

For begining fix this little syntax mistake:
VarProductId = Product.objecrs.get(PId="Product_ID") *Product.objects.get

Comment: Opps but,  nope didn't fix the problem, would be so pissed at myself if that was the problem tho hahah

Answer (score 0):

**"Cannot assign "15": "Cart.Product_ID" must be a "Product" instance."**

Above signifies that you are trying to insert a row in Cart table with Product_Id = 15. Since this is a foreign key, Product_Id should be present in class / table Product. First please insert the value in Product before inserting the row in class Cart. This should work.

Comment: That will raise an exception `DoesNotExist` when he's trying to do `VarProductId = Product.objecrs.get(PId="Product_ID")`.

Comment: I already added a row in the Product database with that PId, but for some reason Cart doesn't recognize them, maybe something wrong with my def str in model?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few this apart from the solution I want to mention:

1. What I feel is somehow the web server you have started has not been
   refreshed. try restarting it if possible. Seems to me that is the
   issue here.
2. If there is a spelling mistake in `objecrs` you will an exception stating is not a valid manager rather than 15.
3. Try to log/print the type of `VarProductId` before assigning it.
4. Don't prefix `Var` for all variables. It is not the way to write clean code. Also everything in python is an object. So there is no
   sense in prefixing it `var`.
5. After checking form.is_valid() always use `form.cleaned_data` to fetch the data you want. Not from request.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer, i will try those solution

Answer (score 0):

Other than your `objecrs` typo, this code should run fine.

Try deleting your `.pyc` files (specifically `views.pyc`) and restarting your development server.

Comment: do you mean the views.cpython-36.pyc in __pycache__ folder above migrations?

Comment: Yeah. Deleting your pycache folder entirely would work too. Your development server is running stale code.

Comment: Can you open up the Django shell and try out your code?

Comment: i will try i forgot how to input date value lol, but i can save Cart just fine in Django Admin

Comment: the query works just fine, i think i somehow messed up the form